# Determining if what's on a frequency is signal, or noise

Tags: signal-identification, noise

I have the spectrum binned into 5kHz bins.  For each bin, I'd like to determine (via software) whether what's in that bin is primarily signal (an FM broadcast station; a ham repeater) or noise (just noise floor - no users).  Is there a standard measurement / algorithm / time-series approach for such a thing?

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II - I was the author of the other post.  The answers to the other post did not solve my problem.  Possibly because I was misunderstood.  Hence trying a different approach.

Comment: How can I find the duplicate question? I´m interested in this topic as well